# Batch file Java class error

Tags: java, class, batch-file

When trying to run below batch file, I get this error

> Error: could not find or load main class AssignFileName

Never had any issues in years until today - any clue?

```
echo on 
d:
cd\driscoll\uar40app\uardata\rt901009003\gl extract
java AssignFileName "psgl_extract.txt"
```

Comment: Do you have any recent upgrades/path changes on the environment ?

Comment: Do you have a file called AssignFileName.class anywhere on your system?  Do you have an environment variable called classpath?  Does the classpath environment variable include the directory that contains AssignFileName.class?  (You need all three answers to be YES).

Comment: Make sure that 'AssignFileName' class is available where your starting batch file. The bat file is not able to class file. It is a class path issue.

Comment: You need to **quote paths with space** in `cd`!!!! plus, do `cd /?` to see the **correct usage** of `cd`

Comment: Thanks for your responses everyone. Yes file exist AssignFileName.class in the same directory. It was working fine until suddenly.... There was a new java version installed recently but we uninstalled it - still no luck :(